# Bootstrap 5 navbar-brand and navbar-toggler behavior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

what makes the navbar-brand element push the navbar-toggler button to the **right** of the navbar in bootstrap 5.0.0?

For example, if I add this line to the navbar before the nav-toggler button, the nav-toggler button will be forced to the right end of the navbar.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>

<button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" data-bs-toggle="sidemenu" aria-label="Navigation Toggle">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

However, if I remove the previous line with the `<a>` tag or place it after the `<button>` element, then the nav-toggler (button) is justified to the **left** of the navbar.

What is it about the navbar-brand class that makes this happen? I would like to be able to get the same effect without having to use the navbar-brand object.

Comment: For the person who edited my post, I rejected the edit because it did not make any substantive change. all you did was placed my code in a third-party code renderer. However, the code above, as is, is not intended to render (or run). It is only there to clarify the question.


Thank you for a valiant attempt at helping, but one should not change a thing simply for the sake of change or to add bells, whistles, or shiny buttons. A thing should only be changed if the change actually improves upon, or clarifies the intended purpose of the original thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour happens due to the `justify-content: space-between;` property of flexbox which is set on the parent element of these two elements.

[image]

You may open the developer window using `CTRL+SHIFT+I` and see this behaviour :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess I need to study up on Flex (on my giant To-Do list). Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, @ImranRafiqRather for all the help. The above graphic is a nice touch.